# decodedURI not displaying properly in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, perl

I have a string encoded in perl using

```
uri_escape ($string);
```

I then pass it to Javascript and decode it via

```
fileName = decodeURIComponent ($somevariable);
```

I then do an alert of the variable and the string displays properly (in this case)

```
his33a;Cell-Line_Fly-biotin-tagged-H33;Tissue_embryo-derived-cell-line;Developmental-Stage_late-embryonic-stage;Compound_80-600-mM;extract_soluble-fraction;sampling_time_point_1-–-2-hours;DNA-tiling-array;Rep-2;Dmel_r54;modENCODE_2523;GSM333854.wiggle
```

However in HTML this is being displayed as

```
his33a%3BCell-Line_Fly-biotin-tagged-H33%3BTissue_embryo-derived-cell-line%3BDevelopmental-Stage_late-embryonic-stage%3BCompound_80-600-mM%3Bextract_soluble-fraction%3Bsampling_time_point_1-%E2%80%93-2-hours%3BDNA-tiling-array%3BRep-2%3BDmel_r54%3BmodENCODE_2523%3BGSM333854.wiggle
```

Comment: I think you want `decodeURI`, not `decodeURIComponent`.

Comment: decodeURI displays his33a%3BCell-Line_Fly-biotin-tagged-H33%3BTissue_embryo-derived-cell-line%3BDevelopmental-Stage_late-embryonic-stage%3BCompound_80-600-mM%3Bextract_soluble-fraction%3Bsampling_time_point_1-%E2%80%93-2-hours%3BDNA-tiling-array%3BRep-2%3BDmel_r54%3BmodENCODE_2523%3BGSM333854.wiggle

Comment: With decodeURI it does not show up properly in the alert properly either.

Answer (score 3):

Perl/`URI::Escape`'s `uri_escape` and JavasScript's `encodeURIComponent` do not do the same thing. To guarantee compatibility, use the `JavaScript` module from CPAN:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use JavaScript;
use URI::Escape;

my $rt = JavaScript->create_runtime();
my $cx = $rt->create_context();
my $string = 'his33a;Cell-Line_Fly-biotin-tagged-H33;Tissue_embryo-derived-cell-line;Developmental-Stage_late-embryonic-stage;Compound_80-600-mM;extract_soluble-fraction;sampling_time_point_1-–-2-hours;DNA-tiling-array;Rep-2;Dmel_r54;modENCODE_2523;GSM333854.wiggle';

# Perl:
say uri_escape($string);
# his33a%3BCell-Line_Fly-biotin-tagged-H33%3BTissue_embryo-derived-cell-line%3BDevelopmental-Stage_late-embryonic-stage%3BCompound_80-600-mM%3Bextract_soluble-fraction%3Bsampling_time_point_1-%E2%80%93-2-hours%3BDNA-tiling-array%3BRep-2%3BDmel_r54%3BmodENCODE_2523%3BGSM333854.wiggle

# JavaScript:
$cx->eval(qq|
function escape_uri(string) { return encodeURIComponent(string) }
|);
say $cx->call('escape_uri', $string);
# his33a%3BCell-Line_Fly-biotin-tagged-H33%3BTissue_embryo-derived-cell-line%3BDevelopmental-Stage_late-embryonic-stage%3BCompound_80-600-mM%3Bextract_soluble-fraction%3Bsampling_time_point_1-%C3%A2%C2%80%C2%93-2-hours%3BDNA-tiling-array%3BRep-2%3BDmel_r54%3BmodENCODE_2523%3BGSM333854.wiggle
```